# How to correctly pass --network parameter to Hardhat scripts?

Tags: ethereum, ethers.js, hardhat

I'm trying to deploy to Goerli, but my deploy script seems to ignore the `--network` parameter.

Here is my `hardhat.config.ts`:

```
import { HardhatUserConfig } from "hardhat/config";
import "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox";
import "hardhat-gas-reporter"
import "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers";
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config();

const env:any = process.env;

const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
    solidity: {
        [...]
    },
    networks: {
        hardhat: {
            [...]
        },
        goerli: {
            url: 'https://goerli.infura.io/v3/',
            accounts: [env['DEPLOYER_PRIVATE_KEY']]
        },
    },
    [...]
};

export default config;
```

Then I run:

`npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.ts --network goerli`

And in my `deploy.ts`:

```
async function main() {
    const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();
    console.log('Using RPC ', ethers.provider.connection.url);
    console.log('Deploying from address', deployer.address);
    [...] // contract deployment code
}
```

However it fails with error "could not detect network". It makes sense because it also logs (from my code):

```
Using RPC  http://localhost:8545
Deploying from address 0x3a5Bd3fBc2a17f2eECf2Cff44aef38bd7dc4fd7c
```

My address is correct, the address logged indeed corresponds to the account that I provided with the private key from dotenv, so it's being read from the config correctly. However, the RPC URL is incorrect: it seems that it's trying to connect to my local RPC and failing.

Why isn't Hardhat respecting the `url` property in the config, and still trying to connect to my local instance?

Comment: Hardhat uses the `hardhat.network.provider` object to connect to the specified network in the command line, try using it instead of the `ethers.provider` object

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
    solidity: {
        [...]
    },
```

to

```
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.4",
  

 networks: {
    goerli: {
            url: 'https://goerli.infura.io/v3/',
            accounts: [env['DEPLOYER_PRIVATE_KEY']]
        }
}

};
```

If you want to deploy on Hardhat you can run `npx hardhat node` and remove goerli and `const env:any = process.env;`.